# How to merge three files with common id in pandas?

Tags: python

I have three files which are users.dat, ratings.dat and movies.dat.

users.dat

```
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
1::F::1::10::48067
```

ratings.dat

```
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275
1::2355::5::978824291
1::1197::3::978302268
1::1287::5::978302039
1::2804::5::978300719
```

movied.dat

```
1193::One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)::Drama
661::James and the Giant Peach (1996)::Animation|Children's|Musical
914::My Fair Lady (1964)::Musical|Romance
3408::Erin Brockovich (2000)::Drama
2355::Bug's Life, A (1998)::Animation|Children's|Comedy
1197::Princess Bride, The (1987)::Action|Adventure|Comedy|Romance
1287::Ben-Hur (1959)::Action|Adventure|Drama
2804::Christmas Story, A (1983)::Comedy|Drama
```

My expected output

```
1::1193::5::978300760::F::1::10::48067::One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest::Drama::1975
1::661::3::978302109::F::1::10::48067::James and the Giant Peach::Animation|Children's|Musical::1996
1::914::3::978301968::F::1::10::48067::My Fair Lady ::Musical|Romance::1964
1::3408::4::978300275::F::1::10::48067::Erin Brockovich ::Drama::2000
1::2355::5::978824291::F::1::10::48067::Bug's Life, A ::Animation|Children's|Comedy::1998
```

I am trying to merge these files without using pandas. I created three dictionary. User id is a common key.  Then, I tried to merge these three files using users keys. But, i did not merge exaclty what i want. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

My code

```
import json
file = open("users.dat","r",encoding = 'utf-8')
users={}
  for line in file:
   x = line.split('::')
   user_id=x[0]
   gender=x[1]
   age=x[2]
   occupation=x[3]
   i_zip=x[4]
   users[user_id]=gender,age,occupation,i_zip.strip()
   file = open("movies.dat","r",encoding='latin-1')

 movies={}
    for line in file:
      x = line.split('::')
      movie_id=x[0]
      title=x[1]
      genre=x[2]
      movies[movie_id]=title,genre.strip()
      file = open("ratings.dat","r")
      ratings={}
      for line in file:
         x = line.split('::')
         a=x[0]
         b=x[1]
         c=x[2]
         d=x[3]
         ratings[a]=b,c,d.strip()
    newdict = {}
    newdict.update(users)
    newdict.update(movies)
    newdict.update(ratings)
    for i in users.keys():
       addition = users[i] + movies[i]+ratings[i]
       newdict[i] = addition

    with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:  
       json.dump(newdict, outfile)
```

My output like this

```
{"1": ["F", "1", "10", "48067", "Toy Story (1995)", "Animation|Children's|Comedy", "1246", "4", "978302091"], "2": ["M", "56", "16", "70072", "Jumanji (1995)", "Adventure|Children's|Fantasy", "1247", "5", "978298652"],
```

Comment: Please fix the indent of your codes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake in your code (apart from messed up indents) is that you make a dictionary out of ratings with user ID as a key:

```
ratings[a]=b,c,d.strip()
```

For your dataset, dictionary `ratings` will end up with value `{ '1': ('2804', '5', '978300719') }`. So all but one rating would have been lost since you have only one user.

What you want to do instead is to treat your ratings data as a list, not a dictionary. And the result you are trying to achieve is also an extended version of the ratings, because you will end up with as many rows, as you have scores.

Secondly, you don't need `json` module, since your desired output is not in JSON format.

Here's a code that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Part 1: collect data from the files

users = {}
file = open("users.dat","r",encoding = 'utf-8')
for line in file:
    user_id, gender, age, occupation, i_zip  = line.rstrip().split('::')
    users[user_id] = (gender, age, occupation, i_zip)

movies={}
file = open("movies.dat","r",encoding='latin-1')
for line in file:
    movie_id, title, genre = line.rstrip().split('::')

    # Parse year from title
    title = title.rstrip()
    year = 'N/A'
    if title[-1]==')' and '(' in title:
        short_title, in_parenthesis = title.rsplit('(', 1)
        in_parenthesis = in_parenthesis.rstrip(')').rstrip()
        if in_parenthesis.isdigit() and len(in_parenthesis)==4:
            # Text in parenthesis has four digits - it must be year
            title = short_title.rstrip()
            year = in_parenthesis

    movies[movie_id] = (title, genre, year)

ratings=[]
file = open("ratings.dat","r")
for line in file:
    user_id, movie_id, score, dt = line.rstrip().split('::')
    ratings.append((user_id, movie_id, score, dt))

# Part 2: save the output
file = open('output.dat','w',encoding='utf-8')
for user_id, movie_id, score, dt in ratings:

    # Get user data from dictionary
    gender, age, occupation, i_zip = users[user_id]

    # Get movie data from dictionary
    title, genre, year = movies[movie_id]

    # Merge data into a single string
    row = '::'.join([user_id, movie_id, score, dt,
                    gender, age, occupation, i_zip,
                    title, genre, year])

    # Write to the file
    file.write(row + '\n')

file.close()
```

Part 1 is based on your code, with the main differences that I save the ratings to a list (not dictionary) and that I added parsing of years.

Part 2 is where the output is being saved.

Contents of `output.dat` file after running the script:

```
1::1193::5::978300760::F::1::10::48067::One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest::Drama::1975
1::661::3::978302109::F::1::10::48067::James and the Giant Peach::Animation|Children's|Musical::1996
1::914::3::978301968::F::1::10::48067::My Fair Lady::Musical|Romance::1964
1::3408::4::978300275::F::1::10::48067::Erin Brockovich::Drama::2000
1::2355::5::978824291::F::1::10::48067::Bug's Life, A::Animation|Children's|Comedy::1998
1::1197::3::978302268::F::1::10::48067::Princess Bride, The::Action|Adventure|Comedy|Romance::1987
1::1287::5::978302039::F::1::10::48067::Ben-Hur::Action|Adventure|Drama::1959
1::2804::5::978300719::F::1::10::48067::Christmas Story, A::Comedy|Drama::1983
```

Comment: Thank you very much andriy. You explanied everything very well.